# Selenium IDE does not display hoverable menu

Tags: selenium, drop-down-menu, regression-testing

Unable to see hoverable drop down menu when I record in Selenium IDE. I want to see that list of menu after hovering. Is there any command? I have used the following commands:

1. waitForVisible
2. mouseOver

Drop down is not displayed like when we hover using cursor.

Here are the commands used:
 open 
/projects/dummysite/    mouseOver id="menu-item-207"    pause 5000    mouseOut id="menu-item-207"

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>open</td>
 <td>/projects/dummysite/</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>mouseOver</td>
 <td>id=&quot;menu-item-207&quot;</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>pause</td>
 <td>5000</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>mouseOut</td>
 <td>id=&quot;menu-item-207&quot;</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: Pleae post both Java and HTML in your question, not the comment.